Failed to launch outlook on Power Automate
I'm new with power automate and i tried to launch outlook But i get this error
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.Desktop.Actions.SDK.ActionException: Failed to launch Outlook ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Outlook.Actions.OutlookActions.LaunchOutlook(Variant& outlookInstance)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Outlook.Actions.LaunchOutlook.Execute(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.ActionRunner.Run(IActionStatement statement, Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 outputArguments)



Silly question, but do you have outlook installed on the machine you are using? it has to be installed.

yes I do have outlook

Probably you are using the new outlook for windows. Outlook automation doesn't support new outlook
Try to use Outlook desktop application. On 20/12/2024, I resolved downloading microsoft 365 and running outlook.
